# Cordova 2.5.0, "AndroidManifest.xml: File is missing"

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I downloaded cordova 2.5.0 and followed the instructions. When I try to "build" the project in Eclipse, I get the following error:

AndroidManifest.xml: File is missing!

But there /IS/ an AndroidManifest.xml in the project.

Comment: How did you add the project to Eclipse? What version of Eclipse are you using, and what version of the ADT plugin are you using?

Comment: Did you try `Fix Project Properties`? See [Step 1 on this page](http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/notepad-ex1.html).

Comment: Latest of everything, all 32 bit, and imported the created project as per the instructions. I did not run Fix project properties.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure how I fixed it. I think I deleted the AndroidManifest.xml file that was in the project. Then I just created a new one in the directory and refreshed and all of the sudden it saw it and stopped complaining....